# How to group continuous ranges using MySQL

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands, date-range

I have a table that contains categories, dates and rates. Each category can have different rates for different dates, one category can have only one rate at a given date.

```
Id        CatId    Date        Rate 
------  ------   ------------   ---------
000001      12   2009-07-07     1
000002      12   2009-07-08     1
000003      12   2009-07-09     1
000004      12   2009-07-10     2
000005      12   2009-07-15     1
000006      12   2009-07-16     1
000007      13   2009-07-08     1
000008      13   2009-07-09     1
000009      14   2009-07-07     2
000010      14   2009-07-08     1
000010      14   2009-07-10     1
```

Unique index (catid, Date, Rate)
I would like for each category to group all continuous dates ranges and keep only the begin and the end of the range.
For the previous example, we would have:

```
CatId    Begin          End            Rate 
------   ------------   ------------   ---------
12        2009-07-07    2009-07-09     1
12        2009-07-10    2009-07-10     2
12        2009-07-15    2009-07-16     1  
13        2009-07-08    2009-07-09     1  
14        2009-07-07    2009-07-07     2
14        2009-07-08    2009-07-08     1
14        2009-07-10    2009-07-10     1
```

I found a similar solution in [the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662545/how-do-i-group-on-continuous-ranges) which did not exactly give the result

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatId, Rate ORDER BY [Date]) AS rnd,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatId ORDER BY [Date]) AS rn
        FROM    my_table
        )
SELECT  CatId AS catidd, MIN([Date]) as beginn, MAX([Date])as endd, Rate
FROM    q
GROUP BY  CatId, rnd - rn, Rate
```

SEE [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5288/9)
How can I do the same thing in mysql?
Please help!

Comment: Why does your example show for `(CatId,Rate)=(14,1)` a resulting range from `2009-07-08` to `2009-07-10` when there is no `2009-07-09` in the underlying table?  c.f. `(CatId,Rate)=(12,1)`, which produces two resulting ranges due to its discontinuity.

Comment: Thanks eggyal, now it's corrected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support analytic functions, but you can emulate such behaviour with [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT   CatID, Begin, MAX(Date) AS End, Rate
FROM (
  SELECT   my_table.*,
           @f:=CONVERT(
             IF(@c<=>CatId AND @r<=>Rate AND DATEDIFF(Date, @d)=1, @f, Date), DATE
           ) AS Begin,
           @c:=CatId, @d:=Date, @r:=Rate
  FROM     my_table JOIN (SELECT @c:=NULL) AS init
  ORDER BY CatId, Rate, Date
) AS t
GROUP BY CatID, Begin, Rate
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fddbd/1/0).

Comment: @vanabel: It is MySQL's [NULL-safe equal to operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Comment: @eggyal Nice answer, upvote. Can you please explain in more detail the trick you used to set the value of variable `@f` (joining with `(SELECT @c:=NULL)`)?

Comment: @MiljenMikic: in this case, the `IF()` will always take the false branch on the first record (due to `CatID` being non-null and therefore different from the `NULL`-initialised value of `@c`).  Consequently, the initial value of `@f` is ignored/overwritten before being read—hence initialisation is unnecessary.

Comment: This SQL's **first running in a session** returns all 11 rows, and returns 7 rows after that. This happens on both MySQL 5.6 and 5.7.  The above sqlfiddle always returns 7 rows as expected.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT catid,min(ddate),max(ddate),rate
FROM (
    SELECT
        Catid,
        Ddate,  
        rate,
        @rn := CASE WHEN (@prev <> rate 
           or DATEDIFF(ddate, @prev_date)>1) THEN @rn+1 ELSE @rn END AS rn,
        @prev := rate,
        @prev_id := catid ,
        @prev_date :=ddate
    FROM (
        SELECT CatID,Ddate,rate 
        FROM rankdate
        ORDER BY CatID, Ddate ) AS a , 
        (SELECT @prev := -1, @rn := 0, @prev_id:=0 ,@prev_date:=-1) AS vars      

) T1 group by catid,rn
```

Note: The line **(SELECT @prev := -1, @rn := 0, @prev_id:=0 ,@prev_date:=-1) AS vars** is not necessary in Mysql Workspace, but it is in the PHP mysql_query function.

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/513b2/21)

Comment: if we remove the record with ID = '000004' your query return (begin:2009-07-07, end:2009-07-16, rate:1) that's not correct because there is a gap, it should return (begin:2009-07-07, end:2009-07-09, rate:1) and (begin:2009-07-15, end:2009-07-16, rate:1). [SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/513b2/1)

Comment: @BoussahelBachir, i have edited the answer. in this case, need to include the condition of datediff to cater the situation you mention.

Comment: You don't seem to be testing `@prev_id` anywhere... what happens if two contiguous dates with the same `Rate` have a different `CatId`?

Comment: Due to i have group by catid, so it will group by catid follow by rn somehow.Thus i do not use `@prev_id` at last. Initially , i did think of to include `@prev_id` in the condition thou.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, still posting a solution that worked for me.
Had the same issue, here's how I got it

Found a good solution using variables

```
SELECT  MIN(id) AS id, MIN(date) AS date, MIN(state) AS state, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM    (
    SELECT  @r := @r + (@state != state OR @state IS NULL) AS gn,
            @state := state AS sn,
            s.id, s.date, s.state
    FROM    (
            SELECT  @r := 0,
                    @state := NULL
            ) vars,
            t_range s
    ORDER BY
            date, state
    ) q
GROUP BY gn
```

More details at : https://explainextended.com/2009/07/24/mysql-grouping-continuous-ranges/