# MySQL user variable used in expression defining it in SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand the following code snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276797/5266608):

```
  SELECT   my_table.*,
           @f:=CONVERT(
             IF(@c<=>CatId AND @r<=>Rate AND DATEDIFF(Date, @d)=1, @f, Date), DATE
           ) AS Begin,
           @c:=CatId, @d:=Date, @r:=Rate
  FROM     my_table JOIN (SELECT @c:=NULL) AS init
  ORDER BY CatId, Rate, Date
```

My confusion is around how `@f` is being assigned. The name `@f` itself appears on both the left and right sides of the `@f := expr` statement. What does it mean when a user variable appears in the expression defining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever used a statement in any programming language like this:

```
i = i + 1;
```

The current value if `i` is evaluated, then add one, then assign the result as the new value of `i`.

It's the same with assignment of `@f` in the SQL expression. The right side of the assignment is evaluated first, using the current value of `@f`. Then the result is assigned to the left side, which may be one of the variables involved in the expression.

Comment: Okay--how does it start though? i.e., what is the initial value of `@f`?

Comment: If you had set `@f` to some other value previously in the current session, it'll have that value. Otherwise NULL.