# How to group data on continuous date ranges

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in which I enter attendance of every employee including annual leave (code: `LAn`) or casual leave (code: `LCa`).

```
+-------+-----------+-----+
|  ID   |   Date    | Att |
+-------+-----------+-----+
|  9999 | 01-Jul-19 | LCa |
|  9999 | 02-Jul-19 | LCa |
|  9999 | 03-Jul-19 | LCa |
| 10000 | 15-Jul-19 | LAn |
| 10000 | 16-Jul-19 | LAn |
| 10000 | 17-Jul-19 | LAn |
| 10000 | 18-Jul-19 | LAn |
| 10000 | 19-Jul-19 | LAn |
|  9999 | 22-Jul-19 | LCa |
|  9999 | 23-Jul-19 | LCa |
|  9999 | 24-Jul-19 | LCa |
+-------+-----------+-----+
```

I am working in MS Access 2016.

It is very similar to this problem: [How do I group on continuous ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662545/how-do-i-group-on-continuous-ranges), but I want a solution in MS Access. Can anyone help me out please?

I want the query to partition data based on dates so that the output looks something like this:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----+
|  ID   | DateFrom  |  DateTo   | Days | Att |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----+
|  9999 | 01-Jul-19 | 03-Jul-19 |    3 | LCa |
| 10000 | 15-Jul-19 | 19-Jul-19 |    5 | LAn |
|  9999 | 22-Jul-19 | 24-Jul-19 |    3 | LCa |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MS Access, you can use a correlated subquery to generate a sequential number.  Then subtract the sequential number from the date to identify the groups:

```
select id, min(date), max(date), att
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t as t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.date <= t.date
             ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) as t
group by id, att, dateadd("d", - seqnum, date)
```

Comment: `group by dateadd("d", - seqnum, date)` Superb solution Gordon 1+.